# Writing a code beautifier

Tags: ruby, code-formatting

I'd like to write a code beautifier and i thought of using Ruby to do it. Could someone show me a place to get started? I've seen a lot of code beautifiers online but I've never come across any tutorials on how to write one. Is this a very challenging task for someone who's never undertaken any projects such as writing a compiler, parser, etc. before?

(Is there another langauge which would be more well suited for this kind of task, excluding C/C++?)

Comment: On this site : a code beautifier for ruby. [rubyBeautifier](http://www.arachnoid.com/ruby/rubyBeautifier.html)

Answer (score 2):

Python has an interesting feature - it exposes its own parser to scripts.  There [are examples](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/533145-ast-pretty-printer/) that use the AST - abstract syntax tree - and do the pretty printing.

I'm not aware that Ruby exposes its own parser to its scripts in such a way, but there are parsers for Ruby written in Ruby [here](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/12/ruby_ruby_parser).

Answer (score 2):

Well... I think the initial steps are what you'd do for any project.

Write a list of requirements.
Describe a user interface to your program, that you like and won't prevent you meeting those requirements.
Now you can write down more of a "code" design, and pick the language that would be easiest for you to meet that design.

Here's some requirements off the top of my head:

- Supports code beautifying of these languages: Ruby, Python, Perl
- Output code behaves identically to input
- Output has consistent use of tabs/spaces
- Output has consistent function naming convention
- Output has consistent variable naming convention
- Output has matching braces and indentation

Make as many as you want, it's your program. ;p  I was kidding about the Perl, but I think every language you support is going to add a more work.

Comment: +1. It's all about finding your requirements and then seeing which tool best meets those, just as for any problem.  E.g. a requirement of "I'd like to learn Ruby" could be just as important as others and skew things in that direction. :)

Comment: Could you tell me what tools I have to use? Do I need to use tools like lex and yacc or are those intended for something else? I did read somewhere that I need to parse the code into tokens or something after which I can handle it but that's all I know about. Thanks.

Comment: Tokenizing lines will definitely be part of your program.  Look at the rubyBeautifier germanlinux linked to, it's not a long program.  It used regular expressions, which is perfect for this.  They are hard to learn, but very useful.

I don't know Ruby, but it looks like you can use .split(delimiter) function on a string to chop it into tokens.  Regular expressions are probably the way to go, though.